# XmlHttpRequest.send() method is returning null when parameters are sent through url

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets

I have a html page in which i wrote a javascript for ajax call
the following is my code

```
var dbParam = JSON.stringify({"name" :"success"});
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
}
}
xmlhttp.open("POST", "MyServlet", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
xmlhttp.send("x="+dbParam);
```

MyServlet is the url pattern for my servlet

In Servlet

```
String s=request.getParameter("x");
This is returning null
```

Answer (score 1):

From your code snippet,i could see a typo while sending "**xmlhttp.send("x="+dParam)**" .Just make sure are you sending the correct variable,here it should be "**dbParam**".

Comment: i even tried with string "x="+"hello" still it is returning null

Answer (score 0):

```
 xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Set content type as above.